# Play Scala JsValue.asOpt type mismatch

Tags: json, scala, playframework

I have this simple function implemented in Play framework.

```
private def buildCreateJs(jsVal: JsValue): JsValue ={

var socialJS = Json.obj("networkId" -> authSource)
val nwUserId = (jsVal \ "id222").asOpt(String)
if(nwUserId.isDefined) socialJS = socialJS + ("nwUserId" -> JsString(nwUserId.get))
socialJS
```

}

When I'm basically trying to check if the Json as a field, in which case I'll put the value of that field into a Json Object.
I got two problems at the same part of the code ((jsVal \ "id222").asOpt(String)):

1. IntelliJ says that "Type mismatch: expected Reads[NotInferedT], actual: String
2. If I run the code (using a function to call a page in the browser), I got "object java.lang.String is not a value"

Can you please help me with this? Thanks a lot

Comment: `asOpt[String]` ..i.e. brackets, not parentheses